# HTML 5 input type month can be modified

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I have a requirement where I want to display Month in using only the first 3 characters. And I also want the functionalities like changing month using arrow keys and Typing in M would show March again typing M would select May like that.

So the question is can I modify HTML 5 input type month to show only first 3 char of month or is there some other element that can be modified to behave this way?

Comment: There are only 12 months, you can create a select dropdown list

Comment: This will give the whole list I wanted the input month like case where there is no drop down and the value changes as per user input

Comment: can you show the html you have so far?

Comment: Its the whole date time picker thing. The thing is in the raw input of date and month I don't want a drop down , I am using the month type of HTML 5 but the problem there is the variation in the month characters is causing design issues. I also require to show only first 3 chars of a month

Answer (score 0):

I could not find some HTML 5 element that does this. So I created this small component of mine with these capabilities.

https://codepen.io/anuprai11894/pen/WxdNYv

```
class Month extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.monthArray=['Jan','Feb', 'Mar','Apr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    this.state=({selectedMonth:this.monthArray[props.month]||0});
  };

  searchAndChangeMonth=(key)=>{
    const _key=key.toLowerCase();
    let k = _.findIndex(this.monthArray,(month,index)=>(index>this.state.selectedMonth && _key===month[0].toLowerCase()));

    if(k===-1){
         k = _.findIndex(this.monthArray,(month)=>( _key===month[0].toLowerCase()));
    }
    if(k===-1 || k===this.state.selectedMonth){
       return;
     }
     this.setState({selectedMonth:k});
  };

  changeMonth=(value)=>{
    const  index=this.state.selectedMonth,
          newMonth=index+value,
          maxIndex=this.monthArray.length;
    if(newMonth > maxIndex){
        this.setState({selectedMonth:0});
    }else if(newMonth < 0){
        this.setState({selectedMonth:11});
    }else {
         this.setState({selectedMonth:newMonth});      
    }
  };
  onValueChange=(event)=>{
    const keyCode=event.keyCode; 
    if(keyCode===40 || keyCode===38){
      this.changeMonth(keyCode-39);
    }else {
        this.searchAndChangeMonth(event.key);
      }
 };
  render() {
    return (<input  onKeyDown={this.onValueChange}
              value={this.monthArray[this.state.selectedMonth]} />);
  }
}


React.render(<Month />, document.getElementById('app'));
```